# Почему данные не отображаются на странице JSP?

Tags: java, веб-программирование, get, jsp, servlet

Main.java:

```
package ru.Mark;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
public class Main extends HttpServlet{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException, ServletException{
              resp.setContentType("text/html");
              String name=req.getParameter("login");
              String password=req.getParameter("pass");
              req.setAttribute("login", name);
              req.setAttribute("pass", password);
              RequestDispatcher disp=getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
              disp.forward(req, resp);


    }
}
```

index.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Page!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>First page!</h2>
<form action="index.jsp" method="post">
Login:<input type="text" name="login"><br>
Password<input type="text" name="pass"><br>
<input type="submit" name="send"><br>
</form>
login: ${login}<br>
password: ${pass}<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Почему логин и пароль не отображается на странице индекса?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что this is SO in russain, so you should ask in russian

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: голосую за бан комментариев типа "this is SO in russain, so you should ask in russian" потому как они на англицком в русскоязычном СО. алсо, господа, мы тут про помощь или снобизм, без желания научить, а тупо покарать?

Comment: Желательно было бы посмотреть `web.xml`, и не говорите что у вас его нет.

Answer (score 2):

вместо этого кода:

```
 RequestDispatcher disp=getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
                  disp.forward(req, resp);
```

Попробуй вот этот:

```
req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(req, resp);
```

Comment: А в чем собственно разница?

Comment: Я не спрашивал как работает диспатчер, читай вопрос внимательно прежде чем отвечать.

Answer (score 1):

У меня была такая же проблема и она решилось сменной jsp страницы. Если у вас это index.jsp, тогда это какая-то `магия` но джава не сетает в индексной странице эти значения. 
Ради примера, вы можете попробовать создать еще одну jsp, но которой будете делать все то же самое, только чтобы это была не мейновая страница.

Вот собственно мой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/487612/servlet-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-setattribite), касательно той же проблемы и в комментариях его "костыльное" решения.